# How to extract specific DATE and TIME from resulted MySQL query in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I want to extract DATE and TIME into two different variables that can be used to display in text boxes.

Here is what I am doing in my code -

```
MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlDataReader reader2 = null;
        cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT lastlogintime from authentication where email=@email";
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", LoggedInUser);
        cmd3.Connection = connect;

        reader2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            string temp = reader2.GetString(reader2.GetOrdinal("lastlogintime"));
            lastloginDateTB.Text = temp.ToString(); // This will give full string as (yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss) into lastloginDateTb
            // Now I want to display date in Date_TB and Time in Time_TB. Note: I have 2 different textboxes as lastloginDateTB & lastloginTimeTB ;
        }
```

This code extract value from authentication table (**lastlogintime** column) into temp variable and displays the same in **lastloginDateTB textbox** but I want to display specific date and time in each of its column.

> Note: Table consist of fieldname - **lastlogintime** which has DATETIME value.

Comment: Why don't you use `SqlDateTime`? Then you cast it to a `DateTime`  get `Date` component and `time`

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the string to DateTime and extract date using ToShortDateString() method and Time using ToShortTimeString() method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 07:00:00 AM");

dt.ToString("HH:mm");
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");
dt.ToString("H:mm");
dt.ToString("h:mm tt");
string date = dateTime.Date.ToString(); //for date
```